# Maven, Jetty and DB2 troubles

Tags: maven, jdbc, db2, jetty

I'm developing a web application and want to use J2EE Form Based Authentication for login purposes. I'm using the Eclipse Maven plugin, jetty, and a DB2 database. So far, I've followed [this tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Realms) and a Head First book in order to configure things (pretty much to the letter), and ended up with the following...
In web.xml:

```
// some stuff omitted
<login-config>
<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
<realm-name>hospital</realm-name>
<form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

In jetty-web.xml:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<Get name="securityHandler">
<Set name="loginService">
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.JDBCLoginService">
<Set name="name">Hospital JDBC Realm</Set>
<Set name="config">hospitalRealm.prop</Set>
</New>
</Set>
</Get>
</Configure>
```

In hospitalRealm:

```
jdbcdriver = com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
url = jdbc:db2:hospital
// user and table config omitted
cachetime = 300
```

When I run the web app using "mvn clean jetty:run" and send login data via the form in login.html (copy&pasted the form with the correct parameter identifiers) I get:

```
ClassNotFoundException for com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver -
```

I don't understand why jetty can't find the class (does it even know the JAR?). I believe it should be contained in classpath, as there is a (compile) dependency in pom.xml. I copied the JARs to WEB-INF/lib as well as WEB-INF/lib/ext, as search results suggested that might fix it (jetty looking stuff up there and all). It didn't. What am I doing wrong here? 
Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Maybe change it to a `runtime` dependency in maven?  I mean, I'm pretty sure you don't have any _compile-time_ dependencies, given this is setup by configuration - this probably means that it's not actually being included in your distribution on the server (no references).